# Javascript apply y coordinate onclick.

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates, event-listener

I'm trying to store `'y'` coordinates for an image in an `array` and cycle through them on click.

I've stored the coordinates in an `array` and the `event listener` obediently changes

The `y` coordinate of my image but using the `array index` rather than the given values.

for example `0,1,2,3` instead of `50 -50 -150 -250`

```
posa = 50;
posb = -50;
posc = -150;
posd = -250;

position  = [posa, posb, posc, posd];

index = 0;

clue1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

//clue1.y = posb;     //works

clue1.y = (index++)%(position.length);

//alert(position);   //returns 50 -50 -150 -250

//alert(clue1.y):    //returns 0 1 2 3 (the y position of my image)

stage.update();

});
```

Many thanks to those who take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

clue1.y = position[(index++)%(position.length)];

Comment: You are a '' genius! That was '' perfect, you've just ended four days of pain! Thank you @ skstar.